# Dell PowerEdge T105 server is dead, is power failure the likely cause?

Tags: hardware, dell, dell-poweredge

Bought this 4 years ago,

Dual Core AMD® Opteron™ 1210; 1.8GHz,2X1MB Cache

Was running my own Apache server and some apps on Ubuntu. Now the server is dead. When I press the power button, there is no response at all. Is this likely a problem of the power supply?  How can I quickly root cause the problem? Is there a fuse of some sort in the power supply?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the looks of things, while its a 'server', it seems to be built around a standard ATX case,and a quick look at dell's website indicates its [probably a standard ATX](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/956/p/19349580/19761955.aspx) - this link also seems to indicate the PSU is shared with [desktop class systems](http://www.hexparts.com/Dell-T100-T105-Dimension-E520-E521-305-Watt-Power-Supply-NH493_p_1662.html). Power supplies die, and 4 years sounds like a plausible time for it to start dying of old age.

PSUs DO have internal fuses, but unless you're an electrician, there's no real point in opening up the PSU. Its a standard, relatively inexpensive component - it'll be faster, cheaper *and* easier to simply replace it with a new component.

Comment: Bought a refurbished PSU from hexparts.com, installed it and the server is up and running again. Installation was very easy. Thanks.

Comment: After 3 more years, the server died again.  Sigh...  I just bought a used one power supply on ebay this time.